# CakePHP exception and error handling

Tags: cakephp, exception, cakephp-2.0

I was trying to write my own exception handler for CakePHP 2.2 but I totally lost in implementation.
http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html

So I decided to use MyController::myAction in exceptions. Can you tell me easiest way to redirect users to myAction and parse error type inside action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation you following, it looks you were on the right track.

You can create your own custom controller to handle exception. See this link: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/exceptions.html#creating-a-custom-controller-to-handle-exceptions